# How can I append the salesPrice value to the list in addToList without calling the function?

Tags: python

I need to add the value of the salesPrice variable to addToList for example, everytime the user is asked "Enter property sales value: " If the user enters the number 2, I need that number to be added to the list (addToList) everytime the getFloatInput function is called. But When I try to append it to the list it does not get the function value of salesPrice. Also everytime the user enters "y" I need it to go back up to getFloatInput so they can enter another property sales value and then that needs to be stored in the list again. I have tried figuring this out on my own plenty of times but I cannot understand it.

```
def getFloatInput():
    while True:
        try:
            salesPrice = float(input("Enter property sales value: "))
            if salesPrice > 0:
                return salesPrice
            print("Enter a numeric value greater than 0")
        except ValueError:
            print("Input must be a numeric value")

def main():
    addToList = []
    while True:
        addToList.append(getFloatInput)
        print(addToList)
        try:
            repeat = str(input("Enter another value Y or N: "))
            repeat = repeat.lower()
            if repeat == "y":
                getFloatInput()
            elif repeat == "n":
                break
        except ValueError:
            input("Enter another value Y or N: ")


getFloatInput()          
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works this code according to your description :)

```
def getFloatInput():
    while True:
        try:
            salesPrice = float(input("Enter property sales value: "))
            if salesPrice > 0:
                return salesPrice
                break
            print("Enter a numeric value greater than 0")
        except ValueError:
            print("Input must be a numeric value")

def main():
    addToList = []
    while True:
        addToList.append(getFloatInput())
        print(addToList)
        try:
            repeat = str(input("Enter another value Y or N: "))
            repeat = repeat.lower()
            if repeat == "y":
                continue
            elif repeat == "n":
                break
        except ValueError:
            input("Enter another value Y or N: ")


main()
```

Comment: Ok I see what you did there!! you added a continue and a break. Wow I cant believe thats what I was missing thank you SO much

Comment: Do you know why the except value error isnt working? Like for example when it asks me "Enter another value Y or N" and I enter "a" I want it to repeat the except value error so the user will enter either y or n